# Google Workspace Custom Addon with Apps Script: load webpage in the sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I've developed and deployed my own custom add-on with some bookmarks in it. Now I'd like to know if it's possible when I click on one of the bookmarks, a webpage is loaded in to the sidebar.

So far, I've come to the conclusion that `.setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.FULL_SIZE) or .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)` is possible. Am I missing something here or is it just not possible?

Thx in advance!

Comment: For anyone wondering the same, I've spoken with a partner engineer at google, and currently this is not possible. Maybe in the future it will be possibe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a website within a sidebar addon. It'll be better if you create a browser extension to do it.

That sounds like a good feature tho, feel free to fill out a feature request on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823911